# Magento 2.1.1: How can we add Payment Information (custom payment) to an order?

Tags: magento2, module, payment

I have a custom payment gateway that pass additional payment information back upon the return to Magento store that I would like to store on the associated order, so that it can be displayed on the admin page, similarly to what Paypal Express Checkout offer as shown below. What would be the best practice to do this (I prefer have it done within a controller action that handle the return).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**A quick reference:**

Take a look the sales order view xml:

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment" name="order_payment"/>
```

As we can see, `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment` block will handle the payment output.
It will get the payment info block:

*vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Payment.php*

```
$paymentInfoBlock = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($payment, $this->getLayout());
```

In Paypal case, the block info is `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Block/Payment/Info.php`. 
Paypal module built the model info to collect and provide access to PayPal-specific payment data: `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Info.php`

**SUMMARY:**

--Create the model info.
--Create the block info to get the info from the model info.

Comment: Thank you for the replying. My 2nd part of question is how do we create the object equivalent of  vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Info.php and then store it into the order? Let's say if I have Info.php for my custom module. Is there a function from Order, Quote, or Transaction object that I need to call to attach this info model for display later?

Comment: @frostshoxx we create your own info block and info model, and then inject the info model on the constructor of info block. You should see more here: `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Block/Payment/Info.php`.

Comment: It seems to me that the class Info is an extension of \Magento\Payment\Block\Info\Cc. Is it still applicable if the payment gateway I'm using does not use credit card?

Comment: I'm not test yet, however, I think it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your key from additional info to your config.xml node like

```
<paymentInfoKeys>wallet_card_4_digits</paymentInfoKeys>
```